# How to check if a word comes alphabetically before or after another word in python?

Tags: python, string, list, alphabetical

From my looking around, it seems that the < and > operators have something to do with comparing strings.

For example, if I do 'Charlie' < 'Daniel' I get True. Does the true indicate that charlie would come first before daniel if they were both added to a list alphabetically?

And if I did 'Danielle' < 'Daniel' and get False, that means alphabetically danielle would come after daniel in a list? So if the first string is less than the second, it comes first alphabetically?

Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes to all that, as long as you're satisfied with using default collation (i.e. 0<9<A<Z<a<z<ü). If you are sorting non-English strings, look into [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) module instead.

Comment: Vandalizing your own questions is contrary to the TOS for the site. You grant copyright when you ask it here.